# difference between on and mon in ExtJs MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs

I need to add click event in my xtype : 'panel' in extjs 4.1.3

But I can do this by two ways.

1. `panel.mon(panel.getEl(), 'click', function(){
        panel.fireEvent('click');
   });`
2. `panel.getEl().on('click',function(){
        panel.fireEvent('click');
   });`

So after doing above code, in controller I can get click event of panel and can do my stuff there. But I can't get difference between these ways.
And also other question in my mind is which is best way?
Please can anybody help me to understand this diff?? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: mon automatically cleans up when panel is destroyed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mon` is used when a component is binding an event to something that we want to remove when the component is destroyed. For example:

```
// Some shared menu
var menu = new Ext.menu.Menu();

var p = new Ext.panel.Panel();
p.mon(menu, 'show', function(){
    p.update('Menu was shown');
});
// This automatically causes the show event on the menu
// to be removed, even though the menu wasn't touched
p.destroy();
```

In your case, a component will always clean up it's element, so it doesn't really matter either way.

Comment: thanks Evan Trimboli... so in code which you gave here..menu will be destroy automatically when panel destroyed...am I right?

Comment: thanks Evan Trimboli...so when I want to destroy another component automatically while panel will be destroy..then I should use mun...am I right ?

Comment: No, the menu won't be destroyed when the panel is. That's just the event listener that will be removed from the menu.